# How to connect to Microsoft SQL Server on a local VM?

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 VM with SQL Server installed on it. I made sure, that in the Sql Server Configuration Manager the SQL Server Browser is running and the TCP/IP protocol is enabled.

I'm trying to connect to the server with Entity Framework (although I'm not sure if it's relevant) and I'm getting this error:

> Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started.

That's the connection string that I'm using:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=False; Initial Catalog=<database name>; Data Source=<server name>
```

Comment: `sql server browser` is not SQL Server, it's a separate service - you don't need this afaik to connect directly to SQL Server by dns name or IP.

Comment: What virtual switch is your VM network interface connected to (External, Internal, Private, or default)? Try specifying the IP address of your VM instead of server name.

Comment: Checked Windows Firewall?

Comment: @DanGuzman I don't know about the virtual switch, I use default gnome boxes program for VMs and there's not a lot of options. I tried connecting with the IP address though and I got this: ```provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server```

Comment: @Dai I tried it with Windows Firewall turned on and completely off, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Seems like you have an Instance Name in your connection string, i.e.: `Data Source=serverNameOrIpAddress\instanceName;`. When an instance name is used the client first sends a request to the SQL Browser service on udp/1434 to resolve the instance name to the TCP port that that instance is listening on, then the client connects to that TCP port to execute queries. You can bypass the SQL Browser service by including the port number in the connection string instead, i.e.: `Data Source=tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress,portNumber;`.